# How to hide native android keyboard in IONIC 2 when clicking on a text box?

Tags: ionic2

How to hide native android keyboard when clicking on text box using IONIC 2? I have installed IONIC keyboard plugin from https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/ link and uses this.keyboard.close();
But still keyboard is opening. Help me how to close the keyboard. I am basically showing DOB from the datepicker plugin in a TEXTBOX[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU5A0.png).

**This is the ts file(datepicker1.ts)**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { DatePicker } from '@ionic-native/date-picker';
    import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';
    @IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-datepicker1',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker1.html',
})
export class Datepicker1Page {
  public today:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private datePicker: DatePicker,private keyboard: Keyboard) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Datepicker1Page');
  }
  openDatepicker()
  {

    this.keyboard.close();
    this.datePicker.show({
      date: new Date(),
      mode: 'date',
      androidTheme: this.datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
    }).then(
      date => {
        this.today=date.getDate()+'/'+date.getMonth()+'/'+date.getFullYear()},
      err => console.log('Error occurred while getting date: ', err)
    );
  }

}
```

**And this is the datepicker1.html page**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>datepicker page</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>DOB</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" name="DOB" (click)="openDatepicker()" [(ngModel)]="today" ng-readonly></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: How will  you enter the text in textbox without keyboard?

Comment: No from the ts file i will placing the date of birth. it is the dob field that will be chosen from date picker.

Comment: keep that as Div tag instead of text box, so keyboard will not open and you can pass the date value into the div

Comment: <div (click)="openDatepicker()" [(ngModel)]="today"></div>

Comment: called the function openDatepicker() from div tag, but it is not working. it is working only for text box. why its happening?

Comment: remove  [(ngModel)] and try using <div (click)="openDatepicker()"> {{today}}</div>  which plugin you are using for datepicker?

Comment: $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-datepicker   
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/date-picker

Comment: <div (click)="openDatepicker()"> {{today}}</div> is not working.Showing "Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '{{today}}' is not a valid attribute name."

Comment: show me the HTML part and the function which you are using for date-picker

Comment: have you tried this? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/ it looks better than native date plugin

Comment: yes I tried that. its okey for me. But wanting to know native date picker plugin.

Comment: Good. check the format in HTML for today, seems to be a cosmetic issue. Also check today variable is defined properly in ts file

Comment: may I send you my code to check? so that you can rectify it.

Comment: yeah please share the code in common repository or you can edit the question with code.

Comment: added the .html and .ts file.   please rectify those where is the problem?

Comment: Mark this as correct answer if you have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed to declare the `today` variable in the class and you missed to add `disabled="true"` in `ion-input` tag. Everything is working fine and I have tested it.

TS File

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';
import { DatePicker } from '@ionic-native/date-picker';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public keyboard : Keyboard, public datePicker : DatePicker) {

  }

  today : any;
  openDatepicker(){
    this.keyboard.close();
    this.datePicker.show({
      date: new Date(),
      mode: 'date',
      androidTheme: this.datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
    }).then(
      date => {
        this.today=date.getDate()+'/'+date.getMonth()+'/'+date.getFullYear()},
      err => console.log('Error occurred while getting date: ', err)
    );
  }

}
```

HTML File

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item>
      <ion-label>DOB</ion-label>
      <ion-input disabled="true" type="text" name="DOB" (click)="openDatepicker()" [(ngModel)]="today" ng-readonly></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Sample App which I have created for your usecase https://github.com/PrithiviRajG/Ionic-3-Native-Date-Picker-example

Comment: did you able to fix the issue?

Comment: i was suddenly ill. i will let you know. plz dont mind.

Answer (score 0):

1) `import { DatePicker } from '@ionic-native/date-picker/ngx';` in app.module.ts and keyboard.page.ts

2)  `public keyboard : Keyboard,` in your constructor inject

3) https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard Take reference from this Official site

```
openDatepickerStart(){

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.keyboard.hide();
    }, 100);

    this.datePicker.show({
      date: new Date(),
      mode: 'date',
      androidTheme: this.datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
    }).then(
      date => {
        this.SelectDateModelDetails.get('StartTime').patchValue(date.getDate()+'/'+date.getMonth()+'/'+date.getFullYear())},
      err => console.log('Error occurred while getting date: ', err)
    );
  }
```