# Hide keyboard in ion-input

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

How can I get the keyboard never show in ionic ion-input?, even when it have the focus. I try with keyboard pluging but when it take the focus, the keyboard appears.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add **disabled="true** in ion-input

```
<ion-input **disabled="true**" type="text" name="DOB" (click)="openDatepicker()" [(ngModel)]="today" ng-readonly></ion-input>
```

Refer this :[How to hide native android keyboard in IONIC 2 when clicking on a text box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092664/how-to-hide-native-android-keyboard-in-ionic-2-when-clicking-on-a-text-box)

Comment: I need that it can take the focus. it does not work.

Comment: what actually you need ? keyboard should hide correct ?